# Can't find file - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, directory, file-conversion, file-not-found, os.path

my code looks like this:

```
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import pyexcel as p

rootdir = r'C:/Users/aleks/Desktop/test'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.xls'):
            new_file = p.save_book_as(file_name=file, dest_file_name=file.split('.')[0]+ '.xlsx')
            os.remove(file)
        else:
            continue
```

Now I know that this part works fine as it returns exactly what I want:

```
rootdir = r'C:\Users\aleks\Desktop\test'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        print(file)
```

Files are correctly listed after using `print(file)`, but i can't convert them to xlsx as there is an error showing up: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file1.xls'`. Which I find weird because I can clearly see the files after using `print(file)`

To clarify, in rootdir there are directories which contain .xls files that have to be converted into.xlsx

Comment: Have you tried using double backslashes instead of single?

Comment: Yes i have, result is still the same unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code. I guess the problem is that you try to delete files in sub_directory that are different from your Python root.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith('.xls'):
            fname = os.path.join(root, name)
            new_file = p.save_book_as(file_name=fname, dest_file_name=os.path.join(root, fname.split('.')[0]+ '.xlsx'))
            os.remove(fname)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still gives same error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Which line gives the error ? I've edited my answer, you can try it again.

Comment: ----> 6 new_file = p.save_book_as(file_name=file, dest_file_name=file.split('.')[0]+ '.xlsx') this line was giving an errror, now it works, thanks, do you mind giving quick explanation why my code didnt work?

Comment: As I said in my answer, the problem is that `name`  is a file located outside your Python root. You need to use absolute path, that why I use `os.path.join(root, fname)`.